# Euler sums question

Tags: sequences-and-series

The following series of the existence of closed values like$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{{k^q}}}} }}{{{n^p}}}}$,
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{{{\left( {2k - 1} \right)}^q}}}} }}{{{n^p}}}} ,\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{{{\left( {2k - 1} \right)}^q}}}} }}{{{{\left( {2n - 1} \right)}^p}}}} ,\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{{k^q}}}} }}{{{{\left( {2n - 1} \right)}^p}}}} .$$
$p, q $are all positive integers and $p \ge 2,q \ge 1$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to calculate the value of the series$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{{{\left( {2k - 1} \right)}^q}}}} }}{{{n^p}}}} ,\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{{{\left( {2k - 1} \right)}^q}}}} }}{{{{\left( {2n - 1} \right)}^p}}}} ,\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{{k^q}}}} }}{{{{\left( {2n - 1} \right)}^p}}}} .$$

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$ S(p,q) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{n^p k^q} $$
Then we have (for $p,q > 1$)
$$ S(p,q) + S(q,p) - \zeta(p+q) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^p k^q} = \zeta(p) \zeta(q) $$
In particular
$$S(p,p) = (\zeta(p)^2 + \zeta(2p))/2$$
However, I don't know of a way to get $S(p,q)$ in closed form for $p \ne q$.